# Start/Stop Azure Function App using ADF Web Activity

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there any provision to start/stop an azure function app via Azure Data Factory Web Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Logic Apps is the simplest way to achieve this.

You can call the below Management API to Start/Stop your Azure Function App:

**START**

```sh
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<FunctionAppName>/start?api-version=2015-08-01
```

**STOP**

```sh
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<FunctionAppName>/stop?api-version=2015-08-01
```

You can use [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity) authentication to authenticate above request.

Below are some screenshots for your reference:

[image]

[image]

Once you enable the Managed Identity for your Logic App , It will create a AD Application with the same name of your Logic App Work Flow.

Now Got to your Function App --> Platform Settings --> All Settings --> Access Control (IAM) --> Click on Add(+) button.

Add AD Application (Created with your Logic App Name) and Provide Contributor role and save.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i wanted to start and stop the azure function on demand using ADF WebActivity, is there a possiblity to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Function can be started based on its trigger. eg. Timer, webhoook etc.
It can be stopped by stopping the function App and existing functions will be stopped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i wanted to start and stop the azure function on demand using ADF WebActivity, is there a possiblity to achieve this ?